# I'm trying to bind this data to Html using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I tried using ng-repeat value,group1,group2

i'm getting

grp1

grp2

abc

def

value1

value2

I need

grp1

```
  abc

     valu1
```

grp2

```
      def

          valu1  

Html:
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="heading in group1"> {{heading}} </li> // heading
<li ng-repeat="subheading in group2"> {{subheading }} </li> // sub heading
<li ng-repeat="val in value"> {{val}} </li> // value
</ul>



JavaScript:

                             $scope.group1 = [grp1,grp2];
                             $scope.group2 = [abc,def];
                             $scope.value = [value1,value2];
```

Comment: sounds like you need to remap your data so each top level of your array has nested arrays contained within. Then you can structure html to have `ng-repeat` within `ng-repeat` to loop over child arrays. Data shown is far too primitive to provide any mapping assistance. WHat you have displayed now shows no relationships between the 3 arrays in your scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template would not use `$scope` directly.  It would be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> {{ keys[0] }}</li> // heading
    <li> {{ keys[1] }}</li> // sub heading
    <li> {{ result }}</li>  // values
</ul>
```

Scope is implied in the template and `{{ }}` are used for interpolation.

Comment: OMG. actually keys[0], keys[1], result are in for loop so i'm geting only one value, so please review the code

Comment: Please review the modified code i'm getting only one value In the Box
// heading
Sales Package
// sub heading
ssssssssssssss
// values  it is not repeating

Comment: what array do you want to repeat?  I'm very unclear on what you are trying to render.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: now please check the code i modified i need to repeat group1 , group2, value simultaniously

Comment: Your 3 ng-repeat are independant so the content of the first ng-repeat will be printed completely before the content of the second ng-repeat. You will need to include them in each other for this to work. Something like 

<li ng-repeat="x in group1"><span ng-repeat="y in group2"></span></li>